# Find corner cell of TileMap?

Tags: android, libgdx, tile, tiles-game

Problem when detecting corner cell of tile map???

```
private void getTiles(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, Array<Rectangle> tiles) {

TiledMapTileLayer layer=(TiledMapTileLayer)WorldRenderer.map.getLayers().getLayer(0);

TiledMapTileLayer layer1 = (TiledMapTileLayer)WorldRenderer.map.getLayers().getLayer(1);

        layer_Height=layer1.getHeight();
        layer_width=layer1.getWidth();

        leftcornerCell=layer1.getCell(0, 0);
```

It calculate the screen *x/y* while i want to give map *x/y*.

and gives result nullpointer exception.... Meeans not finding the cell at perticuler position.

How to find out corner cell of any **Tilemap** in **LibGdx**???

Comment: If you're getting an NPE in the above code, its not because `leftcornerCell` is null.  Nothing dereferences that.  Probably `layer1` is null.

Comment: No P.T. **Layer1** is not null it gives current position cell is null.  if  there is another solution to find corner cell of tile map than please post.

Comment: yea a Cell can be null if there isnt any Tile at the map. You dont save empty cells. So catch if the Cell is null ...

Comment: Cells which would be empty at load time are never created as a memory optimization. As @BennX noted, verify the cell is non-null before using it.

Comment: @nEx.Software the name of the Asker is MobiDev hehehe :p